# Image Display in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have to display image name provided in a file. say `image.txt` and then make 
those images as links. On clicking the link another set of image will be 
displayed which is available in `imagename.txt` (e.g. "`1.jpg.txt`") file.

Please tell how to do it.

Function Used for Display Image :

```
function imageDisplay($fileName)
{
$readfile = file($fileName);
// Create a loop that will read all elements of the array and print out
// each field of the tab-delimited text file
$fh = fopen($fileName, "rb") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$count =10;
for ($k=0; $k<=$count; $k++)  
    {

        list($imageName) = fscanf($fh,"%s");
        $path = "images/";
        $path = trim($path.$imageName);     


?>
    <body bgcolor="gray">
    <img src="<? echo $path; ?>"  alt="<? echo $path; ?> " vspace="5" hspace="10" />

<?php
}
fclose($fh);
}
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Actually I am able to display image from a file, but not able to get how to get image name on clicking the image.

Comment: Please post any code you have, so we can diagnose the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me provide you a general guideline,

1. You will write a script to read the file text. Depending on your image name seperator (eg. enter key or comma or semicolon,) you will split the text to get your image names.
2. Using a foreach loop, you will render all those images.
3. Every image will be referencing to another page with it's unique id as parameter.
4. When the image will be clicked, you will be redirected to new URL, there depending on the unique id, you will fetch other set of images.

Take it step by step and start coding it. You may come across issues in which case you can post more questions :) But the best way to move forward is to start coding.

**UPDATE :**
Every image needs to be wrapped by a hyperlink with it's unique id attached, eg.

```
<a href="secondImageSet.php?imageId=1"><img src="abcd.jpg"></a>
```

On the next page you will take the image id and display matching results. Note taht second set of images should be associated with first image.

Comment: Please explain 3rd & 4th step. I have updated code for my image display.

Comment: I am doing like this <a href="secondImageSet.php?imageId="<? echo $path; ?>">, but imageId is coming blank. Where is the problem.

Comment: That would be error prone since paths are long and you risk writing them incorrectly. The best way is to have a small unique id. And for next set of images, define them in a way that associated parent image id is stored together.

Comment: Actually I thought giving imageId as imagename itself will be good. How, to give unique id to each images b'coz this display image is in loop.

Comment: You can do a couple of things 1) You name your image as eg. 1.jpg and then simply split the name using dot and take out the "1." 2) Another way is to store your file in a format like 1:[ImagePath] , so that 1 is unique id and [ImagePath] is image path. For second set of files, you will again simly store as 1:[FirstChildImagePath],1:[SecondChildImagePath]

Comment: How to get imageId value on the called page i.e. secondImageSet.php to use this value to call the display function

Comment: If you assigned the image id as a querystring a parameter that's after questionmark then it will be available to next page in your request collection which you can access by $_GET